# Ag-grid onPasteStart event access to paste data for async process

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

Am trying to access user paste data when onPasteStart/onPasteEnd event fires. Running Angular 12. The resulting javascript object includes all ag-grid methods and I cant find the resulting data that is pasted. I cant print the string of the object and ctrl-f because it gives an error with the object being circular.
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/clipboard/#clipboard-events

My intention is to take the paste and use resulting data to make a api request and then use the response to modify the paste. Tried using ag-grid processDataFromClipboard but came across errors as I imagine it doesnt support async functions.

Here is an angular plnkr example. All I need is to consol.log params.value with the pasted data and starting row of the paste.
https://plnkr.co/edit/q6cZQbX7LdHzozy9

```
    console.log('Callback onPasteStart:', params);
  }

  onPasteEnd(params) {
    console.log('Callback onPasteEnd:', params);
  }
```

It sounds simple so I feel like I must be missing an obvious solution